# GoCD - Task Plugins not adding tasks

Tags: go-cd

I have setup a GoCD server and agent (on a Windows machine if that matters). I am using it to build a .NET application. I have installed a few Task plugins (Powershell, Xunit-converter) and when I restart the server I see those as loaded and installed without issue in the plugin admin screen.

However, when I go to create or edit a job, I do not see these new tasks in the "Add Task" dropdown.  I can get around the powershell one by using a Custom command, but I need to be able to convert my MsTest ouptut to Xunit so that it can display the results in the Test Results Tab.

Comment: You can also workaround the conversion by using a Custom command